# Elastic Search stops automatically in Server

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, magento2-cloud

Home page, Product detail pages are working on My store. But Product catalog page is not working.

Getting message "Out of Memory : Killed Process" message on Server Console

```
root@lamp-ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:/var/www/xxxx.com/public_html# [11487454.118006] Out of Memory : Killed Process 3126401 (java) 
total-vm: 5455888kb, anon-rss:1484068kb, file-rss:0kb, shmem-rss:okb, UID: 114 pgtables:4384kb oom_score_adj:0
```

Getting Error in Browser.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException): No alive nodes found in your cluster

```
 #1 Elasticsearch\Transport->getConnection() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php:94]
#2 Elasticsearch\Transport->performRequest() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:281]
#3 Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}() called at [vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:28]
#4 React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then() called at [vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php:55]
#5 GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then() called at [vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Core.php:341]
#6 GuzzleHttp\Ring\Core::proxy() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:329]
#7 Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:227]
#8 Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->performRequest() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Transport.php:105]
#9 Elasticsearch\Transport->performRequest() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Namespaces/BooleanRequestWrapper.php:38]
#10 Elasticsearch\Namespaces\BooleanRequestWrapper::performRequest() called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Namespaces/IndicesNamespace.php:279]
#11 Elasticsearch\Namespaces\IndicesNamespace->exists() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Client/Client.php:85]
#12 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Client\Client->indexExists() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Index/IndexOperation.php:103]
#13 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\IndexOperation->indexExists() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Index/IndexOperation.php:117]
#14 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\IndexOperation->getIndexByName() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/ContainerConfiguration.php:193]
#15 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\ContainerConfiguration->getIndex() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/ContainerConfiguration.php:94]
#16 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\ContainerConfiguration->getIndexName() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/Builder.php:161]
#17 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\Builder->create() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCatalog/Search/Request/Product/Aggregation/Provider/FilterableAttributes/Modifier/Coverage.php:108]
#18 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Search\Request\Product\Aggregation\Provider\FilterableAttributes\Modifier\Coverage->getCoverageRates() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCatalog/Search/Request/Product/Aggregation/Provider/FilterableAttributes/Modifier/Coverage.php:59]
#19 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Search\Request\Product\Aggregation\Provider\FilterableAttributes\Modifier\Coverage->modifyAttributes() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCatalog/Search/Request/Product/Aggregation/Provider/FilterableAttributes.php:81]
#20 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Search\Request\Product\Aggregation\Provider\FilterableAttributes->getAggregations() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/ContainerConfiguration.php:156]
#21 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\ContainerConfiguration->getAggregations() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/ContainerConfiguration/Aggregation/Resolver.php:37]
#22 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\ContainerConfiguration\Aggregation\Resolver->getContainerAggregations() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/Builder.php:205]
#23 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\Builder->getContainerAggregations() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCore/Search/Request/Builder.php:147]
#24 Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Search\Request\Builder->create() called at [app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCatalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Fulltext/Collection.php:608]
#25 Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection->prepareRequest() called at
```

Here is Our Server details.

- Magento 2.4.1  PHP : 7.4

  Server Details:  Digital Ocean   8 GB Ram 160 GB Disk   4 vCPUs LAMP
  on Ubuntu 20.04

I found elasticsearch has stopped. I started elasticsearch service the Catalog page is working for some time. Again I will get the same issue.

I need to solve the issue Permanently. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a lot of RAM for Elasticsearch. I this only the elasticsearch machine or the whole Magento 2 installation? You should at least double it. Also you will need to go through bootstrap checks on elasticsearch - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/bootstrap-checks.html

Comment: I just recently dealt with similar issue and fixed it by going through the bootstrap checks. But yours is really clear - 8G for Magento 2 installation is too low.

Comment: Hi kalvi, Thanks for reply. I will do bootstrap checks. and How much GB RAM is good for Magento 2 ?

Comment: Minimum 16GB, but it will be still a bit too low. I would go for 32GB if you can. I ran a DEV server with nightly imports at 16GB and it was too low. You should try, but no promises when the traffic comes in. My DEV server did not have any traffic, so there's a big difference. If you have a small shop, 16GB might work. Elastic was blazing fast on it, but MySQL was having a rough time. RAM would be always maxed out and dipping into the NVME ssd from time to time.

Comment: Here is a thread of my issues from stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69184558/elasticsearch-crashing Just go over the bootstrapping and increase RAM to at least 16GB.

Comment: Hi, Our store is having around 500 Products only. Is 8GB RAM enough?

Comment: Try going through the bootstrap checks and see if you can get it to work. I dont think 8GB will work, its just too low for Magento 2. Magento 1 you can run on 1GB of RAM and it will be blazing fast. Magento 2 requires too many technologies to run. Catalog and catalog search are now directly connected to the Elasticsearch, so whenever a Google/Bing hits your catalog page, there will be a request to Elasticsearch. Magento removed MySQL search from Magento 2.4.x so everything now depends on Elastic. Elastic down = catalog down.

Comment: Kalvin, Yes you are right, Magento 1 works on low requirements. Which Cloud server is best ? I am using Digital ocean.

Comment: DigitalOcean should work ok. You can get much cheaper if you run baremetal on a private hosting. But private hosting is much more fragile so DigitalOcean is great. Make daily backups and you will be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129900/discussion-between-thanjeys-and-kalvin-klien).

Answer (score 0):

You must restart the elastic search and apache for this.
To have Elasticsearch automatically reload when the system restarts, use the following commands:

First, reload the systemd configuration:

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
Then, enable the Elasticsearch service with:

sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service